# Adding new collection in FireStore db deletes the other ones

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im working on a project for school with FireStore.
I need to add 4 fields individually to my FireStore db. They are called "player1", "player2", "player3" and "player4". When the first person runs the code, "player1" is added. When the second person runs the code, "player2" is added, but "player1" is deleted. Same for the other 2. Which is weird, since it should not be doing that. Here's the code that adds the field

```
public void initPlayer(){
        getFirestore();

        HashMap<String, String> playerQuote = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> players = new HashMap<>();

        playerQuote.put("money", "140");
        playerQuote.put("name", ControllerManager.getPlayer().getPlayerID().toString());
//The PlayerID is different for every player
        playerQuote.put("color", "Green");

        playerQuote.put("haan", "0");
        playerQuote.put("gans", "0");
        playerQuote.put("kat", "0");
        playerQuote.put("hond", "0");
        playerQuote.put("schaap", "0");
        playerQuote.put("bok", "0");
        playerQuote.put("ezel", "0");
        playerQuote.put("varken", "0");
        playerQuote.put("koe", "0");
        playerQuote.put("paard", "0");


        players.put((ControllerManager.getPlayer().getPlayerID()), playerQuote);
        this.db.collection("game")
                .document("Players")
                .set(players);

    }
```

The code is written in such a way that it first checks what players are in the database. So if player1 is present, but player2 isn't, player2 will be added. But since then player1 is deleted, the next person to run the code will add player1 again and delete player2.
I really have no idea why its not working the way it should. Im not deleting anything anywhere, so why does it still delete anyway?
Here's how the database should look like:
[image]

Comment: To understand better, do you need to have all 4 players within the same document or as different documents within a collection?

Comment: they are in the same document, but in collections inside that document. Ill add a picture of a full database to my original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing `.set(players)` to `.update(players)`.
`.set()` is rewriting the document, while `.update()` is updating the document. Note that `.update` does not allow a `<string, hashmap<string, string>>`, so I had to change it to `<string, object>`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Players` in your Firestore screenshot is a **Document**, **not** a Collection.

The Firestore data model always alternates Collections and Documents, so you can't immediately nest a `Players` collection under the `game` collection. Usually I'd have a game ID as a document level in between them, but if there's only one game - give the required document a fixed name, such as `default`.

So then the data model becomes:

```
games (collection)
  default (document)
    Players (collection)
      player1 (document)
        ... fields
      player2 (document)
        ... fields
      player3 (document)
        ... fields
      player3 (document)
        ... fields
```

---

If you want to stick to your current data model and store all players in a single document, you will have to make sure that players don't overwrite each other's data. This means, you'll want to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to first read the `Players` document and then update it.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't mean collection, I meant field. I'm trying to add fields to a collection. Each field being an increment of the one before. So player1, player2, player3 etc. I'm not overwriting anything, since the fields are all different names. So why would player2 overwrite player1?